# How to query a result to only show IDs of users with a timestamp less than a given year

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table that stores all data that a user answers. I am trying to find out which user_id's have not updated anything in the system since Jan 1, 2012.

Each user will have about 500 item_id's in the database. The query I am trying to process will return the DISTINCT user_id of every user that has not updated their data since a given year. Not all item_id's have to be updated so if any item_id has a dt greater than the datetime I am trying to find then I need to ignore them, even if it's 1 record. I only want user_id's that have not updated a single field since 2012.

Any help or push in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

**The table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_results` (
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`result` text NOT NULL,
`specifier` text NOT NULL,
`dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
UNIQUE KEY `item_id` (`item_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: This updation is set in the `dt` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a subquery that gets their latest `dt` value (*MAX VALUE*) like this one below (*it works if you want to **get all the columns** of the last update of the user.*)

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM item_results b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id, MAX(`dt`) lastUpdated
            FROM item_results
            GROUP BY userID
        ) a ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
               a.lastUpdated = b.`dt`
WHERE DATE(a.lastUpdated) < '2012-01-01'
```

or simply (*the one you are looking for.*)

```
SELECT user_id
FROM item_results
GROUP BY userID
HAVING DATE(MAX(`dt`)) < '2012-01-01'
```

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why this was so difficult for me but you saved me a lot of time! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

How about HAVING?

```
select user_id, max(dt)
from item_results
group by user_id
having max(dt) < '2012-01-01'
```